# Elasticsearch - Group by a key then filter sum another field greater than a value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index with some docs like this:

```
{
"user_id": 1,
"join_room": 1
},
{
"user_id": 1,
"join_room": 1
},
{
"user_id": 2,
"join_room": 1
},
{
"user_id": 2,
"join_room": 2
}
```

I want to get users (group by user_id) that have sum(join_room) greater than 2

I executed query like:

```
{
"aggs": {
    "join_room": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_join_room": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "join_room"
          }
        },
        "sum_join_room_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "joinRoom": "sum_join_room"
            },
            "script": "params.joinRoom>2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it always return all docs in the result
Please help me write a query that return the result that contain only user_id having sum_join_room>2

Thank you very much!

Comment: The `Query` part will have an impact on both the document being returned as well as the Aggregation. But the aggregation will not filter documents.